# which way would be faster? error suppressing @$_REQUEST['x'] or going thru isset($_REQUEST['x'])

Tags: php, error-handling, isset

Using the isset is an additional function call, but nevertheless is the recommended practice. 
In the following particular example, what would be faster?

I sense that the first would be faster. Otherwise, could somebody shed some light as to why the second would be faster -if so?

```
if (@$_REQUEST['x']=='1'):
    define ('X','1'); 
else:
    define ('X','0');
endif;

//or

if (isset($_REQUEST['x'])):
    if ($_REQUEST['x']=='1'):
        define ('X','1');
    else:
        define ('X','0');
    endif;
else:
    define ('X','0');
endif;
```

Comment: Suppressing errors is a bad idea. Even if it is faster, don't do it.

Comment: Thanks Mike. I do know that the recommended way is to go with the option 2. And I did point out that. The question has to do with the way PHP works.. Could still be the second (and the better) way to be faster? The question is all about that.

Comment: It could be faster, yes. Because PHP doesn't have to throw a notice or warning on every iteration and then suppress the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best practice dictates avoiding the suppression operator, so go with isset(). If you're concerned enough with micro-optimization to consider the difference, you should know that PHP still handles suppressed errors even though they're not displayed. Any optimization theoretically gained by @ would likely be lost by the error processing.

Best practice also dictates specificity in getting input from external sources. I'd also recommend choosing $_POST or $_GET as alternatives.

Comment: `PHP still handles suppressed errors even though they're not displayed. Any optimization theoretically gained by @ would likely be lost by the error processing.` will get you the right answer.